# How to jump to an id further down the page with jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is it possible to link to another id further down the page with jQueryMobile? In regular HTML you can do this:

```
<a href="signup">Signup below</a>
```

And then further down on the page

```
<h2 id="signup">Signup here</a>
```

Although this does not seem to work in jQueryMobile and I'm unable to find a solution.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this , hope it works

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(#signup).offset().top}, 1000);
```